# my program is not printing out the outcome

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, printing, linked-list

i made a linked list in c to sort the words in a text file in order. the insert function is to add a node after reading a line which has the word and the meaning separated by :. The file is just lines of a dictionary with a word:meaning format. when i ran the code, it didn't print anything and didnt have an error message

```
type here
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

struct node 
{
    char word[30];
    char meaning[50];
    struct node *next;//링크
};


void insert(struct node **head, char *word, char *meaning) 
{
    struct node *new_node = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    strcpy(new_node->word, word);
    strcpy(new_node->meaning, meaning);
    new_node->next = NULL;

    if (*head == NULL) //빈 리스트
    {
        *head = new_node;
    } 
    else if (strcasecmp((*head)->word, word) > 0) //첫위치 삽입
    {
        new_node->next = *head;
        *head = new_node;
    } 
    else //보통
    {
        struct node *curr = *head;
        while (strcmp(curr->next->word, word) < 0) 
        {
            curr = curr->next; //탐색위치 head에서 시작, 계속 1칸씩 옮겨가며 찾기
            if(curr->next==NULL) break; //if the next node is null, break, insert new_node at the end
        }
        //순서 제대로 찾으면 그 위치에 연결
        new_node->next = curr->next;
        curr->next = new_node;
    }
}


void print_list(struct node * head) 
{
    struct node * cur=head;
    while (cur->next!= NULL) 
    {
        printf("%s : %s\n", cur->word, cur->meaning);
        if(cur->next==NULL){
            return;
        }
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    FILE *fp;
    char line[150];

    fp = fopen("randdict.txt", "r");

    if (fp == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Unable to open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    struct node *head = NULL;

    while (fgets(line, 150, fp)) 
    {
        char *new_word = strtok(line, ":");
        char *new_meaning = strtok(NULL, ":");
        insert(&head, new_word, new_meaning);//알파벳순으로 입력

    }

    fclose(fp);

    print_list(head);

    return 0;
}
```

i tried modifying the print_list function by getting an if return statement even when i already had a condition in the while loop that would help me break out of the loop.

Comment: When `fopen` fails, you should print an error message to stderr (*all* error messages should be written to stderr!) and that message should include the name used as well as the reason for the failure.  The simplest way to do that is the idiomatic: `if( (fp = fopen(name, "r")) == NULL ) { perror(name); exit(1); }`

Answer (score 0):

I re-ran your code at my site without changing anything and that worked as supposed~

*randdict.txt*

```
d:sdf 
a:asfdd
b:sdf
g:bfd
j:gdf
6:gdfg
e:gww
f:wwe
h:r2ssd
j:ewrw
```

I got this kind of output:

```
6 : gdfg
a : asfdd
b : sdf
d : sdf
e : gww
f : wwe
g : bfd
h : r2ssd
j : ewrw
```

, which, I think, is correct according to your requirements...

The only suggestions here can be

- Check randdict.txt file persmissions.
- Check content of randdict, otherwise
- Make sure that list is filled with data
- Make sure we are both compiling the same code :)

And also,

- Don't forget to add cleanup routine for your list, now you have memleak
- It is not advisable to use strtok() *(it is deprecated now)*, use [strsep](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html)() instead

Comment: the randdict file is a txt file with that format but longer. does it have to do with the fonts being normal when i open it on one program(memo) but broken when i read it in vscode?

Comment: Are they ASCII symbols? It is more likely to be that problem.

Comment: they're a mix of english and korean. the korean part of the font is messed up in vscode.

Comment: the part of the txt file looks like this when i open it in vscode credulous : adj.���縮 �ϴ�
burnet : n.����Ǯ�� ����(�Ŀ�)
metalise : vt.�ݼ����� ������
lumen : n.(������ ����)���
immune : a.�鿪����
sadiron : n.�ٸ���
drape : vt.�ָ��� ��� ���ڰ� ����
berserker : n.(������ ������)������ ����
statist : n.��������(�ֱ�)������
stodgy : adj.��ȭ�� �� �� �Ǵ�
underlease : n.����
handyman : n.�⿪��
howitzer : n.�����
chartography : n.�����ۼ���(=cartography)

Comment: the strange thing is that when i write the comments on my code, the korean language shows up fine. the text file is the only thing that shows korean like this